# Can't access page data with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know I must be missing something obvious but I've spent the past 2 hours trying to work this one out. What I'm trying to do is get some information from the active tab, specifically a variable from the URL and the content of a textarea.

I can't seem to retrieve either of these from within my Chrome extension

Here is my ticket.js

```html
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
 console.log(tabs[0].url);
 var ticketID = getQueryVariable("id");
 console.log(ticketID);
 var inputTicket= document.getElementById('bottom_message').value;
 console.log(inputTicket);
});
```

Now when I run it nothing happens. My popup.js is blank and I currently don't need it to do anything popup related, however, do I need to reference ticket.js within popup.js?

Here is my manifest

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Autosave",
  "description": "Extension Ticket system to autosave text in a ticket",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
 "tabs"]
 
  "content_scripts": [
   "matches": ["https://portal.ticketsystem.co.uk/*"],
   "js": ["ticket.js"]
}
```

Comment: It could be, however, my popup.js is called as a content_script so shouldn't it be accessing the page? I've renamed my popup.js to ticket.js and updated the manifest, then created a blank popup.js. Now it does nothing. Do I have to reference ticket.js within popup.js? I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: `chrome.tabs` is not available to a content script. And you don't need it in this case, either. You can get the current url from `location.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest has errors. Doesn't Chrome indicate this when loading the extension? Compare with yours and note that I added a few ,[]{}:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Autosave",
  "description": "Extension Ticket system to autosave text in a ticket",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://portal.ticketsystem.co.uk/*"],
    "js": ["popup.js"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, this is my first attempt at an extension. I've been testing by only editing the js files and not reloading the manifest. I'll try this

Comment: Whenever you update the code files, you need to go to chrome://extensions and reload the extension. When updating the manifest itself, you have to completely remove and readd the extension. I feel your pain; Chrome is a conundrum

Comment: Aaaand it works. Fantastic. That's a mistake I won't be making again in a hurry. Thank you

Comment: For quick small additions / prototyping, check out Snippets in Chrome. I have been using it lately, and it's saving me a lot of CTRL-R in the Extensions screen: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets

In order to run those snippets with necessary privileges, you may have to change the filter in the top part of the console from <top frame> to the name of your extension.

Comment: [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) is pretty alright for JSON validation. Note that JSON doesn't allow for dead-end commas, so for example you can't do `var myObj = { food: "fish", drink: "seawater", }` (this is actually allowed and encouraged in Perl's object notation for example, but JSON is very strict). Anyway, glad you solved it and good thing it wasn't something serious like a browser bug :)